# Firestore Call is freezing my app temporarily - Xcode/iOS/Firestore

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, google-cloud-functions

I am making a call in my SwiftUI app which will add a document to my Cloud Firestore database. The issue is this is taking around 5 seconds to complete and rendering the app useless for those 5 seconds. I think this could also be down to the cloud functions running when the document is added however I am not sure.

I have tried, rather unsuccessfully so far I might add, to look at using other threads however this is to no avail. Can anyone provide some advice?

This is how I am calling the function:

```
Button(action: {
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        addCard(time: "", text: "\(userSettings.username) Recorded")
    }
}){
    Text("Another One")
}
```

This is the actual function that is running.

```
func addCard(_ card: Card) {
    do {
        _ = try store.collection(path).addDocument(from: card)
    } catch {
      fatalError("Unable to add card: \(error.localizedDescription).")
    }
 }
```

As I think it could also be my Cloud Functions causing an issue, here it is too:

```
exports.logActivities = functions.firestore.document('/{collection}/{id}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        return admin.messaging().send({
            "notification": {
                "title": 'New Record',
                "body": snap.data()['text'] + ' a  new "Tell Em Lad"'
            },
            "apns": {
                "payload": {
                    "aps": {
                        "sound": 'notiSound.wav'
                    }
                }
            },
            "topic": 'client'
        });

    })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) The trigger of your Cloud Function happens asynchronously, so can't be causing the slowdown in the app. You could also verify that yourself, by temporarily removing the Cloud Function, and testing if that impacts the performance. 2) I don't think the `DispatchQueue.main.async` is needed, and in fact I wonder if it causes the problem. Firebase already performs all network/disk I/O off the main thread, so I recommend removing that dispatch queue call and testing how that impacts performance. If it makes no difference, you at least know the code is not needed. :)

Comment: If it performs these off the main thread, howcome the app freezes all the time? I hoped the Dispatch would work and it makes no difference so I can remove it - I was just hoping there could be some ways of performing in the background so I can continue use the app

Comment: Run a search for 'asynchronous process.'